# What is the mortality rate of Mt St. Elias?

Tags: safety, mountaineering, rescue

Mt St. Elias is a mountain on the border of Canada and Alaska. I believe it has the fastest relief from sea level of any mountain in the world.

I've read somewhere that it has a higher mortality rate than Everest. That makes sense to me since Everest is so well traveled and there is the help of sherpa teams whilst climbing. Elias is very remote and if you fall or run out of food, there aren't people that can find you. I don't have a source for my very specific mortality rate of 'higher than everest' and I was wondering if anyone else did. :P

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Mt Elias isn't even in the top ten for number of deaths. It comes in in 24th place according to https://www.shughal.com/25-of-the-deadliest-mountains-in-the-world/ with Everest at number 1. This site takes into account the ratio of deaths to number of attempts, as well as total deaths.

For the top ten we have:

```
10 - The Eiger
09 - Annapurna
08 - Cerro Torre
07 - Mount Fitz Roy
06 - Mont Blanc
05 - Naga Parbat
04 - The Matterhorn
03 - Denali
02 - K2
01 - Everest
```

Comment: I don't see where the site says it ranked the ratio Deaths to Number of Attempts.   The material under each mountain is a mish-mash of number of deaths, death rates and purely qualitative info.  What did I miss and where is it?

Comment: Also it must be looking at only specific routes, there's no way Eiger is up there if you also consider the standard ascent.

Comment: This was the best of the four sites I found with rankings. I did a bit of googling for actual data - it took a while but confirmed Everest and K2 as top, and Elias way down the list. ab2 - yes it's a mish mash. imsodin - the Eiger numbers are pretty bad actually.

Comment: The ordering on that site is essentially random.  Everest is not #1 either by raw numbers (the Matterhorn has 500+ kills to Everest's ~250) or by death rate (Annapurna's 32% exceeds Everest's 4%).

Comment: @Mark - you are cherry picking. Everest has far higher death rate than Matterhorn, and far higher numbers than Annapurna. Using all the figures you can see why they have ordered that way.

Comment: @RoryAlsop So what are you saying the ordering criteria is then?  Unless it's something concrete, the list is meaningless.